# Display error message next to textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I just want to ask on how to display error message next or near to textbox if the user enter an already exist ID. Once the user enter an id that already exist the error message will appear next or textbox which says : ”ID already exist enter another id”

I have this code in inserting data to database:

```
Private Function AddUser() 


If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtID.Text) Then MsgBox("Please enter id") : Return False
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFname.Text) Then MsgBox("Please enter firstname") : Return False


        Access.AddParam("@ID", txtID.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Course", cbxCourse.SelectedItem)
        Access.AddParam("@Yr", cbxYear.SelectedItem)
        Access.AddParam("@Fname", txtFname.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Lname", txtLname.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@Mname", txtMname.Text)

             Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO StudentInformation ( ID, Course, Yr, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName) ; ")

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Return False

        MsgBox("Student was added successfully.")
        Form1.RefreshGrid()
        Me.Close()

        Return True


End sub
```

Comment: You should split that into 2 methods: one to perform data validation, and one to insert after the data has been validated.  Your code would be easier to read and manage.  Look at the ErrorProvider for tagging which control have errors and what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likes your really asking two questions from your code.

The first is how to tell if the ID is a duplicate or not. 
The second is how to display an error message.

For the 1st question, if you have ID set as a index you should be able to catch the exception (if not you will have to query the database for that ID)

For the 2nd, since your using winforms (opposed to WPF) I've found putting a label on the form next to the textbox and setting some properties on that label works fairly well, and as long as your project doesn't get to big its easy to manage.

```
Private Function AddUser() 

  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtID.Text) Then MsgBox("Please enter id") : Return False
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFname.Text) Then MsgBox("Please enter firstname") : Return False

  Access.AddParam("@ID", txtID.Text)
  Access.AddParam("@Course", cbxCourse.SelectedItem)
  Access.AddParam("@Yr", cbxYear.SelectedItem)
  Access.AddParam("@Fname", txtFname.Text)
  Access.AddParam("@Lname", txtLname.Text)
  Access.AddParam("@Mname", txtMname.Text)


  Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO StudentInformation ( ID, Course, Yr, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName) ; ")

  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then 
     Label1.text = Access.Exception
     label1.visible = true 
     return false
  end if 

    MsgBox("Student was added successfully.")
    Form1.RefreshGrid()
    Me.Close()

    Return True


End sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. But i want to display the error messag right after the user enter a duplicate id. Do u know how to that? Thanks

Comment: Then the message will gone once the user enter the new id

Comment: You will have to just the database ... if thats the goal then you should probably do a database "select" in the textbox lose_focus

Comment: What is the name of the text box where they put in the ID

Comment: The name of the textbox is TxtID